# Python Optional equivalent for Sequence

Tags: python, type-hinting

Assuming T = TypeVar('T')
Optional[T] hint is interpreted to Union[T, None].
Is there any equivalent for Sequence hint, so that it will be interpreted to Union[T, Sequence[T]]?

Comment: why do you need this kind of annotation?

Comment: @AzatIbrakov: There are some built-in functions that behave like this, so it's not *that* weird. See `min`/`max` (which is either one iterable argument or more than one scalar argument), or `str.endswith`'s ability to take a single `str` or a `tuple` of `str`.

Answer (score 1):

You can define such a type like this:

```
T = TypeVar('T')
MaybeSequence = Union[T, Sequence[T]]

foo: MaybeSequence[str]
```

Comment: Alias hint may be an option. Thanks.